# Ftp folder permission not granted

Tags: php, file, ftp, directory

I have ftp server which store my websites uploaded files. I am putting uploaded images into "upload" directory and then displaying on them to webpages with link to my photo editor tool.

Some how I can not access my ftp files in my photo editor. I figured that it is permission problem, but when I go to change permission for my upload directory files it fails to changes and says

"CHMOD 777 realtors.jpg: Operation not permitted."

let me know if any idea on how to solve this.

Comment: are you changing permissions from ftp application?

Comment: You need to check with your sysadmin. In most cases something changed in the server that is causing this.

Comment: what kind of changes we are talking about

Comment: If I knew, I'd have told you :)

Comment: ok thanks sorry the pun was not intended